# Java equivalent for C# HttpContext

Tags: java, spring-boot

What is the Java Equivalent for HttpContext in C#? I need to convert the following to Java. This code is basically extracting a cookie.

```
// This method returns the username from the login cookie, or null if no user is logged in.
public string ExtractUser(HttpContext context)
{
   // Get the correct cookie from the request
   var Cookie = context.Request.Cookies["dummyUser"];
 
   // Return the cookie's value if it exists
   if ((Cookie != null) && (Cookie.Value != null))
      return Cookie.Value;
 
   // Return null otherwise
   return null;
}
```

Code base from here: https://sisense.dev/guides/sso/jwt/#actions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `HttpServletRequest`
See [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getCookies()) `getCookies()` method

```
public static String getCookie(HttpServletRequest req,String name) {
  Cookie[] cookies = req.getCookies();
  if(cookies!=null) {
    for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
      if(cookie.getName().equals(name)) {
        return cookie.getValue();
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: thanks, I also have to do something here, with redirectUrl,  would this work? I will try out, thanks,   https://sisense.dev/guides/sso/jwt/#actions-5

Comment: context.Response.Redirect("./default.aspx");

Comment: Try this -https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect(java.lang.String)

Comment: see link here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70790782/java-equivalent-for-c-sharp-httpcontext-which-has-both-request-and-response

Comment: Spring MVC apps should rarely interface with servlet APIs. Spring has its own types for retrieving cookies or other headers.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yeah I know that ,I answered as per OP's requirement ,there is no point in downvoting the answer ,is there?

Comment: Which requirement specifically? I don't see them mention Servlets. I don't see them mention any Java library. All I see is `spring-boot` tagged which might indicated Spring MVC. If anything, the question should be closed as unclear.